# How to handle Screen dim for android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Can anybody help please how could be handle the Screen dim so that widget will not update at that time. Its keeps the Screen on all the time.

I could handle the Screen OFF and Screen On Intents and check it in BroadcastReceiver not to update the widget while screen is OFF. But there is no intent for Screen dim.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PowerManager` class to check wither the screen is on/off at points where you need to.

```
PowerManager pw = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if(!pw.isScreenOn())  //check wither the scr is off/on
    {
        wl = pw.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeUpBuddy");
        wl.acquire();
    }
```

Comment: PowerManage check Screen on/off only, not Screen dim. 
I need to check Screen Dim.

Comment: Hmm...what about this: save value of the screen at the beginning, and then just test the current (when the display dims) with that initial value. like:
//save value
`WindowManager.LayoutParams lpcurrent = getWindow().getAttributes();
if(lpcurrent.screenBrightness==brightAtBeginning) // do something`